# ASP.NET Membership Configuration Tool - Change Password?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, membership

How do I change my user's password with the ASP.NET configuration Tool? I can't and I guess its because I need to do something to the web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASP.NET Configuration tool does not support changing passwords.  You would need to implement this in your application.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Easiest thing to do is put a asp:ChangePassword control on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can.  The Configuration Tool does not look like it was set up to be used in this manner.

Would it be acceptable to write down the user's information, delete him/her, then recreate the profile?  Or would you lose data doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can only give the option to reset password. why dont you do that? Thats better.